# Trick to feed chicken and not neighborhood's pigeons?

Tags: chickens

How can one feed 4 chicken in a small garden, without having the pigeons off the neighborhood stealing most of their food?

The only solutions which have worked so far have been

1. to sit with them while they feed (three times a day) , and taking whatever feed they did not eat inside; and
2. to feed them in a 2 cubic meter cage (and freeing them after they are done eating).

They are cumbersome and time consuming. I did try to design a feeding system with suspended boxes which would deliver seeds when the chicken would peck on it, but

- if I left it too sensitive, the flapping of the wings of the pigeons (sometimes as many as 14!) were moving it and delivering the food; while
- if I made it too hard, the chicken would not manage to activate it.

Any suggestions of alternate techniques to try will be welcome. I cannot be the first one to have this problem!